# ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

```
def m_array_pre(x=0, y=0):
    market_array_pre = [] #market return array for pre-event window
    for i in prior_event_window:
        market_array_pre.append(market_return_table.cell(1, y+i).value)
    market_array_pre = pd.Series(market_array_pre)
    return market_array_pre

def s_array_pre(x=0, y=0):
    stock_array_pre = []
    for i in prior_event_window:
        stock_array_pre.append(stock_return_table.cell(x,y+i).value)
    stock_array_pre = pd.Series(stock_array_pre)
    return stock_array_pre

def OLS(x, y):
    X = sm.add_constant(x)
    mod = sm.OLS(y,X)
    res = mod.fit()
    return res.params

row = 0
col = 0

for r in range(stock_return_table.nrows):
    for c in range(stock_return_table.ncols):
        if stock_return_table.cell(r,c).value >= 0.1 or stock_return_table.cell(r,c).value <= -0.1:

            x = m_array_pre(r,c)
            y = s_array_pre(r,c)

            coefficients = OLS(x,y)
            ari = ARi(r,c)
            sheet_result.write(row, col, ari)
            col = col + 1
        row = row + 1
        col = 0
```

When I execute this code and it says "ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data)."
Anyone can help me with this? I am new to python.